# Save image in folder when registering user in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How to save image (photo) of user when registering user in MVC application? I want to save image at same time when user's other information is saved into database.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read the help files and in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). SO is not a code writing service. Do some research, then show the code you have tried indicating what is not working

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the image from your registering form, usually stablishing an input type file to do so (don't forget to change your form to multipart/form-data).

When you send your form, you can get on the controller a HttpPostedFileBase element with the same name as your input type file element, this object will hold the posted file.

Then, using wisely System.IO.Directory and System.IO.File you can save the HttpPostedFileBase element to FileSystem.

I advise to keep a database reference between user record and it's saved image, so you can keep trace of uploaded images, deleted ones, and so on